# Is there a way to modify and rename a column that is within a RECORD in BigQuery, and then keep this column with the same name and location as before?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a `RECORD` in BigQuery with the structure:

```
Parent
|___Child_1
|___Child_2
|___Child_3
|___...
```

`Child_1` is of type `TIMESTAMP`, so I would like to convert it from a `TIMESTAMP` string to an `INT64` that represents the number of milliseconds since Unix Epoch. This is done via the [unix_millis](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#unix_millis) function.

I am having trouble getting this done for nested fields. Below are my attempts:

```
select *, unix_millis(parent.child_1) as parent.child_1 from `dataset.table`
```

When I tried the above, the query editor in BigQuery underlined "child_1" in "as parent.child_1", and gave the error `Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "."`

Why I expected this to work is because, for non-nested fields, it is possible to use `unix_millis` and then use the `AS` operator to rename the column.

So how would I go about performing the `unix_millis` function and then make sure that the resulting column has the same name and location within the `RECORD` as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
  REPLACE((
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(UNIX_MILLIS(child1) AS child1)
    FROM UNNEST([parent])
  ) AS parent)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using some simplified dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, STRUCT<child1 TIMESTAMP, child2 STRING, child3 INT64>(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'test1', 123) parent UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, STRUCT<child1 TIMESTAMP, child2 STRING, child3 INT64>(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'test2', 456)
)
SELECT * 
  REPLACE((
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(UNIX_MILLIS(child1) AS child1)
    FROM UNNEST([parent])
  ) AS parent)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  parent.child1   parent.child2   parent.child3    
1   1   1599154064128   test1           123  
2   2   1599154064128   test2           456
```

while original data was

```
Row id  parent.child1                   parent.child2   parent.child3    
1   1   2020-09-03 17:29:09.512794 UTC  test1           123  
2   2   2020-09-03 17:29:09.512794 UTC  test2           456
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Mikhail! Just a follow-up question, how would I need to change the syntax in order to change doubly-nested or n-nested fields in a `RECORD`?I.e. what if `child_1` has a `child_1_1_...`?

Comment: glad it worked for you. as of follow up question - it is hard to answer it inside the comments and without proper details. Please post new question with details and example of data and expected result so I (or someone else on SO) will be able to help :o)

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry that it took some time to post the question, I wanted to try and figure it out myself... I was unsuccessful, but hopefully, you can teach me how to get it done!
The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63730863/can-i-modify-a-column-that-is-within-multiple-nested-records-in-bigquery-and-th)

Comment: sure. but I think you should edit this new question with some more specific example of let's say 2 or 3 levels of nesting. as it is right now  - with N levels - it has less chances for good answer - but it is up to you :o)