# Can I modify a column that is within multiple nested RECORDs in BigQuery, and then keep this column with the same name & location as before?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This question is a follow-up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728449/is-there-a-way-to-modify-and-rename-a-column-that-is-within-a-record-in-bigquery).

I have a `RECORD` in BigQuery with the structure:

```
Parent
|___Child_1
|___Parent_1
   |___Child_2
   |___Parent_2
      |__Child_3
      |___Parent_3
          ...
```

Each "Child" in this case represents its nested level. i.e. Child_`n`, where `n` is the nested level.

As in the previous question, each Child_`n` is of type `TIMESTAMP` string, and we use the `unix_millis` function to convert it to `INT64` (time since Unix Epoch).

**My first attempt:**

```
SELECT * 
  REPLACE((
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(UNIX_MILLIS(child_n) AS child_n)
    FROM UNNEST([Parent.Parent_1.Parent_2...Parent_n])
  ) AS Parent.Parent_1.Parent_2...Parent_n)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Here, the query editor underlined "Parent_1.Parent_2...Parent_n" from "AS Parent.Parent_1.Parent2...Parent_n", and gave the same error as before, `Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."`.

**My second attempt:**

> Note that {n-1} and {n-2} in the below query represent Parent `RECORD`s that are one and two levels higher in a hierarchal structure, respectively.

```
SELECT *
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      ...
      REPLACE(
        (
        SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(UNIX_MILLIS(child_n) AS child_n)
        FROM UNNEST([Parent_n])
        )
        AS Parent_n from UNNEST([Parent_{n-1})
      AS Parent{n-1} from UNNEST([Parent{n-2}]))
    ...
    AS Parent)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

This time, the query editor underlined the "AS" portion of "AS parent_n from UNNEST([parent_{n-1}])". It gave the error message: `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS`.

As in the previous post, how would I go about performing the `unix_millis` function and then make sure that the resulting column has the same name and location within the nested `RECORD` as before?

Comment: if your use case assumes some reasonable max level of nesting - the solution from previous post can be easily extended (just by repeating that logic as many times as max nesting level you have). Obviously this is not right approach if your max level is let's say more than 3 or 5. In which cases yo need different solution - either based on dynamic scripting or just using JS UDF passing whole hierarchy to UDF and processing it recursively with javascript, etc. Hope this gives you some options to try

Comment: Meantime, so which is option your case is  - some limited (up to 3-5) level of nesting or really dynamic with far more than 3-5 levels?

Comment: The use case is dynamic, so what I'm doing in order to create the query is developing a recursive function in Python in order to go through each nested `STRUCT`, and then create the appropriate query.

Comment: oh, of course, if you plan to invoke your query from with client like Python - you don't need JS UDF or BQ scripting, just construct the query in Python - good luck :o)

Comment: Just as a clarification, do you know how many levels of nesting will your data have? Also do you want to change only the last field of the nested struct (such as **Child_n**)?

Comment: Good question, @AlexandreMoraes. I'm interested in seeing how a general query should be constructed, for any child, on any level. The answer for the first level was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728449/is-there-a-way-to-modify-and-rename-a-column-that-is-within-a-record-in-bigquery) by @Mikhail, and this question aims to get a general answer. Furthermore, I'm curious if there is a better way to achieve this other than through many nested `REPLACE`s...